# How do I double click an .rtf file in file manager to open it with libreoffice?

Tags: unity, libreoffice

Running Ubuntu 16.04, unity
Using Files 3.14.3 (the default file manager). Have libreoffice installed. I have a variety of .rtf files which libreoffice reads perfectly. However, despite making libreoffice the default application to open an .rtf file, double-clicking the file does nothing, yet double clicking .docx and .odt files works normally. This looks like a simple problem but I cannot fix it. It's also a pain because I use those files a lot.

In case someone was going to ask, I use the right click on file name/properties/"open with" method to make libreoffice the default application.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your launcher doesn't have %f at the end of the exec line

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click an rtf file
2. Properties
3. Open With
4. Select "LibreOffice Writer"
5. Check "Set as Default"

Done! You may need to `killall nautilus; nautilus & exit` if it doesn't update the new default right away.

Edit:
Hmm, I just noticed you said this doesn't work. This method worked for me perfectly, so I am not sure, here is another method that might help:

1. Install (if you don't have it yet) and Open Ubuntu Tweaks
2. Admins
3. File Type Manager
4. Text
5. "Rich Text Document"
6. Double-click and select "LibreOffice Writer"
7. Close

Again you may need to reset nautilus or log in & out to see the changes.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu Tweak is considered abandonware at this point, so don't rely on it too much.